# Convert an array of 3D tensors to single 4D tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to convert an array of 3D tensors (images) to a single 4D one, so I can pass them as values to the `model.fit` which does not seem to accept `Tensor3D` arrays.

The idea would be

```py
4dTensor = tf.tensor4d(batch)
```

I am actually using javascript, but either a python or js solution would probably work as the Tensorflow API is similar.

The error of this procedure is:

```bash
Argument of type 'Tensor4D' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Tensor3D[]'.
  Type 'Tensor<Rank.R4>' is missing the following properties from type 'Tensor3D[]': length, pop, push, join, and 26 more.ts(2345)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use [`tf.stack()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stack):

```
4dTensor = tf.stack(batch)
```

Comment: great, i missed that one, thank you